# Jquery XML Data Sorting By Date

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, timestamp

I have some XML which I am reading by jQuery and printing on screen.

This is XML

```
<users>
   <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <fname>Umair</fname>
      <timestamp>2011-03-18T03:41:00-07:00</timestamp>
   </user>
   <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <fname>Neil</fname>
      <timestamp>2011-03-18T03:41:00-07:00</timestamp>
   </user>
</users>
```

This is JS

```
$(xml).find("user").each(function(index, user) {
   var timestamp = $(user).children("date_time:first").text();
   //the dt has date and time in such format 2011-03-18T03:41:00-07:00
   //more code which generates below html and add to the userTable
   //<tr>
   //   <td>
   //      <div>First Name</div>
   //      <div>2011-03-18T03:41:00-07:00</div>
   //   </td>
   //</tr>

   //$("#userTable").append(...all rows here...); 
});
```

This is HTML

```
<table id="userTable">

<table>
```

This is working perfect though the only thing I want to do is sorting this list of users when shown through HTML table. Is there a jQuery plugin I can use or any way around?

Comment: Umair, it would really help if you gave us a few lines of the relevant HTML, so we can see what you have an what you are trying to do with it. Regards

Comment: Umair, see my answer below. Convert the date strings to a Date object, use "valueOf" to get the number of milliseconds since 1971 then sort numerically using this. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin called $.timeago which did the magic.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) will do the trick.

Comment: Actually I have table having many rows but each having single cell which has divs shown as cells. So the timestamp is in 4th div of a every cell. It won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple to sort by dates using the Date object. See a similar example I put together using the Date object and a neat use of BACKREFERENCES of the global RegExp object at:

http://jsfiddle.net/elusien/eZ3RQ/

You should be able to modify it to your purpose.